How do I create an email from a template
I am trying to open an email template (.msg) for editing, but the code keeps going to "catch" after trying to open the template.
I keep getting this error

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Estimator.exe

This is the code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Text;

// Create emails
Outlook.Application outlookApp = InitializeOutlook();
string msgPath = @"C:\Users\andyk\OneDrive\Projects\Visual Studio\Estimator\files\Template.msg";

try
{
    // Open template
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(msgPath);
    mailItem.Display();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error opening template: {ex.Message}");
}
finally
{
    // Clean up COM objects
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlookApp);
}


Most likely that means the MSG file is not a MailItem. Can it be something else? Contact? Appointment? Task?
Change that line to
dynamic mailItem = outlookApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(msgPath);
MsgBox(mailIten.Class);

and make sure you get 43 (which is OlObjectClass.olMail)
